# Does Cypress 4.0 supports Firefox 58 version

Tags: cypress

We have a specific requirement of making sure our application runs on Firefox version 58. Does Cypress latest version 4.0 can support it. (headless mode)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Checking it yourself would be the first thing you should do.

Answer (score 0):

This answer won't age well, but Cypress launched with support for Chrome-family browsers (including Electron) and is progressively adding support for additional
browsers - [including a beta for Firefox and Edge as of version 4.0](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/06/introducing-firefox-and-edge-support-in-cypress-4-0/)!

Please see the Cypress [Browsers documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers) for up-to-date information.